# Встретил в коде непонятный символ << подскажите для чего он

Tags: javascript

Есть участок кода:

```
function makeHash(source) {
  var hash = 0;
  if (source.length === 0) return hash;
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    var char = source.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
    hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
  return hash;
}
```

Что значит вот в этой строчке:

```
hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
```

символ `<<`?

Answer (score 4):

Битовая операция.
Сдвигает двоичное представление значения hash на 5 разрядов влево, заполняя освободившиеся справа разряды нулями.

Читайте учебник, там всё расписано: https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Comment: спасибо за совет